# Android Studio/Kotlin : Gradle error - cannot find compile() method for arguments [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I am using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 6. I've been having some trouble with the `build.gradle` (Project) file.

The `build.gradle` file is as follows :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
        ext.support_version = '26.0.1'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-
                plugin:$kotlin_version"
            compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
            compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

The error that I get is :

> Error:Error:line (13)Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
>   Open Android SDK Manager.

Please help me solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `compile` dependencies from the top level `build.gradle` and put it in your app level `build.gradle` `dependencies`, which would be available under `app/src` in Project view.

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1"
}
```

The app level dependencies (which mostly starts with compile) should be put under app level `build.gradle` file, and not under top level `build.gradle`.

Actually, the `build.gradle` file is written using Groovy language and `compile` is a method invocation. In Groovy, we can [leave the parenthesis for top-level expressions](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses). And that's why you are getting an error like:

> Could not find method complie()

Answer (score 1):

You **can't use these lines** in your **top level** file:

```
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
 compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
```

Remove them and use them in the **module file**.